# Slice of slices with different types in golang

Tags: go, slice

Context: I want to use the slice data structure in golang to make a 2-D feature vector. This feature vector should be a slice that consists of slices of different types, sometimes strings, int, float64 etc.

As of yet, I can achieve this with a map (below), is there a way to implement this with a slice?

```
map := make(map[int]interface{}}
```

What should be more like:

```
featureVector := []interface{[]int, []float64, []string ...}
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

It works as expected, you're just using wrong syntax. The element type of the slice is `interface{}`, so a [composite literal](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Composite_literals) to initialize it should look like `[]interface{}{ ... }`, like in this example:

```
featureVector := []interface{}{[]int{1, 2}, []float64{1.2, 2.2}, []string{"a", "b"}}
```

And you can treat it like any other slice:

```
featureVector = append(featureVector, []byte{'x', 'y'})
fmt.Printf("%#v", featureVector)
```

Output (try it on the [Go Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/RPy5RWkIrb)):

```
[]interface{}{[]int{1, 2}, []float64{1.2, 2.2}, []string{"a", "b"}, []uint8{0x78, 0x79}}
```

But know that since the element type is `interface{}`, nothing prevents anybody to append a non-slice:

```
featureVector = append(featureVector, "abc") // OK
```

This also applies to the `map` solution.

Comment: Well, if we're being technical, strings are _essentially_ slices.  They are freely convertable to `[]byte` and back.  The only functional difference is that slices are immutable, and their slice header structure is a machine word smaller because their cap and len are by definition equal.

Comment: @Kaedys Adding a single `string` value was just an example, I could've just used an `int` too. And if we're at it: a `string` is a read-only slice of bytes _in effect_, but it is not a slice. The language spec allows to treat it similar to a slice in many cases, but still `reflect.TypeOf("abc").Kind() == reflect.Slice` is `false`.